# Clearing unreferenced python objects, simple case

Tags: python, garbage-collection

I would like some clarification on the following

```
my_func(a):
   b = a.copy()  # now you have 2 objects obj_1 and obj_1.copy
   change(b)
   return b

a = obj_1
a = my_func(a)
```

After the assignment of my_func() return value to a, I guess that the    original object obj_1 remains "unreferenced" (**right?**)

and must be deleted (**right?**)

this is done automatically by Python's garbage collector (**right?**)

this applies to any type of object,    for example pandas dataframes (**right?**)

[image]

Comment: Thumbs-up on sketching. :)

Comment: overkill right? :)

Comment: Yes, the original object `obj_1` will no longer be referenced. Yes, it will be deleted *eventually*. Yes, by Python's garbage collector. No, some of built-in Python objects won't be destroyed until the interpreter shutdown, even if your code has no references to them.

Comment: @vaultah isn't this an answer?

Comment: Yes and No: non-mutable objects (`None`, booleans, int, floats, str, tuples, frozensets, etc.) are not changed by `change` function, you'll get a new instance. And they don't have `copy` method. You should use `copy.copy(a)` instead which correctly handle non-mutable objects.